# delete Static Block tabs in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

please visit this link

http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/index.php/acrylic-whiteboard-1200-x-1800mm.html  [galarainbow theme]

below under "add to cart " button, you can see

"DETAILS" "UNDEFINED", PRODCUT TAGS UNDEFINEd UNDEFINEd

here, how to remove 3 "UNDEFINED" texts.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the js file `/skin/frontend/default/galarainbow/js/gala_rainbow.js`.
specifically this method

```
function () {
    var $=jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($('.box-collateral').length > 1){
            $('.product-collateral').each(function(i) {
                $(this).wrap('<div class="tabs_wrapper_detail collateral_wrapper" />');
                $(this).prepend('<ul class="tabs_control"></ul>');
                $(this).children(".product-collateral-item").addClass("ui-slider-tabs-content-container");

                $('.box-collateral', this).addClass('tab-item').each(function(j) {
                    var id = 'box_collateral_'+i+'_'+j;
                    $(this).addClass('content_'+id);
                    $(this).attr('id',id);
                    $('.tabs_wrapper_detail ul.tabs_control').append('<li><a href="#'+id+'">'+$('h2', this).html()+'</a></li>');
                });
                $("div.tabs_wrapper_detail .product-collateral").sliderTabs();
            });

        }
    });
}
```

I assume that this takes the product blocks and turns them into tabs.
But for the sections that don't have a `H2` tab this line `$('.tabs_wrapper_detail ul.tabs_control').append('<li><a href="#'+id+'">'+$('h2', this).html()+'</a></li>');` creates an `undefined` tab.

I don't really know how you can fix it, but this is the best place to start debugging.

**[EDIT]**
try replacing this line:

```
 $('.tabs_wrapper_detail ul.tabs_control').append('<li><a href="#'+id+'">'+$('h2', this).html()+'</a></li>');
```

with

```
if (typeof $('h2', this).html() != 'undefined') {
         $('.tabs_wrapper_detail ul.tabs_control').append('<li><a href="#'+id+'">'+$('h2', this).html()+'</a></li>');
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for helping me again and again. i will try....

Comment: Good luck. I'll send you the bill later :)

Comment: haha.... thanks, wait, this one, not yet done, i will try and ask you hundreds of doubts....

Comment: this is galarainbow.js file =>http://pastebin.com/Gin3X7yR

your code starts from line 279, 

as this line is in 292  $('.tabs_wrapper_detail ul.tabs_control').append('<li><a href="#'+id+'">'+$('h2', this).html()+'</a></li>');
}); what i have to do now?

Comment: @user3483987. See my update. Maybe it works

Comment: as always.... perfect.... Thanks a lot.... it's not easy to solve jquery javascript in magento. you done a gr8 job again....